# Unwrapping Struct vs Class within Swift Combine Publisher

Tags: swift, struct, option-type, combine

I am attempting to post a struct via notification centre, and then processing it with a subscriber elsewhere. I have confirmed that the object within the notification is indeed an optional with the the Or object within it. The following code snippet works when the struct is converted to a class, however not with a struct - throwing the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__SwiftValue' (0x7fff89b99a48) to 'Recogniser.Gate' (0x7fff89b91168)

Is there any reason for this? And is there anything that I can do to solve this?

```
protocol Gate { var description: String { get } }
struct Not: Gate { var description: String { "Not" } }
struct Or: Gate { var description: String { "Or" } }

var gateSubscriber = NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: .gateRecognised, object: nil)
    .map { notification in return notification.object as! Gate }
    .sink(receiveValue: { gate in print(gate.description) } )

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .gateRecognised, object: GateType.buildGate(of: .or))
```

Comment: I assume it is Swift bridging API confuses you converting `nullable id` to `Any?`. `Notification`+`NotificationCenter` is concept initially designed to work with NSObject objects, ie. reference types, and never intended to work with structs, ie. `values`. Actually interface of `NotificationCenter.Publisher` shows that it works only with `AnyObject`. So what you are trying to do just does not work, because should not work.